# How do I get the dimensions of an NSView at init time?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, graphics

I have a custom view (`NSView` subclass), and I would like to store some data based on the dimensions (width/height) of the view when the view is instantiated, i.e. before `drawRect` gets called.

I would expect to be able to use `initWithFrame`, and take the bounds from the passed-in `NSRect`, but if I examine the data in the debugger, I just get an `NSRect` instance with `(x=0, y=0), (width=0, height=0)`. Presumably it's not initialised yet?

More puzzling is that if I log the frame width to the console, I get the value twice:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        CGFloat width = frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"width: %f", width);
    }
}
```

This code logs:

```
21/10/2011 09:40:55.733 Test App: width: 480.000000
21/10/2011 09:40:55.818 Test App: width: 0.000000
```

It's as if initWithFrame is running in two separate threads and we have some kind of race condition. What's the correct way to get the frame width when the view is initialised?

**UPDATE [SOLVED]:** This issue has now been resolved. It turns out that I had two instances of my `NSView` subclass in Interface Builder. One was drawn as a `Custom View` and the other was an `Object` in the side panel. I hadn't realised that adding an object to the side panel caused it to be instantiated at runtime. Removed the object and my code now works.

Comment: If I were trying to debug this, I'd look to see if I was calling initWithFram myself and having it automatically by an InterfaceBuilder relationship?

Comment: It's being called automatically since I have a `Custom View` in IB, with its `Class` field set to my `TestCanvas` class (which subclasses `NSView`). I'm not 'manually' instantiating `TestCanvas` anywhere in my code. Is it possible that it's getting called once when the `NSWindow` is created and again when the `Custom View` inside it gets created or vice versa?

Comment: Maybe, but the times on you log, suggest it's getting called with the 0 size after the correct size. Just put a conditional, checking if the size is 0. If it isn't process the data as you wish?

Comment: Interestingly, they don't always occur in that order. Sometimes I get 0 then 480, which lends weight to my race condition theory. The conditional you suggest will get me working (thanks!), but it *is* a hack, and i'd eventually like to understand what's going on. I might try creating a minimal working example from scratch and see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've found the cause of the problem, see update above.

Answer (score 0):

The frame passed in initWithFrame is the frame used by the view, are you sure you are not creating two views, or calling this twice?

Comment: I have an `NSWindow` inside a .xib, and inside that there is an `Custom View` which has it's `Class` field set to `TestCanvas`. Inside TestCanvas subclasses `NSView` and provides the implementation  of `initWithFrame`. Everything works as expected (I can draw in the view with `drawRect`, except that `initWithFrame` is getting called twice. It's possible that I'm getting two TestCanvas instances, but I can't tell why.